# Inserting casted values from other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner in SQL and have a small problem that I'm trying to overcome. I want to insert to column `WorkYears` these values:

```
INSERT INTO Employees (WorkYears) 
VALUES (CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(HireDate) AS INT))
```

But I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'HireDate'

Column `HireDate` is in table `Employees`, too and is of `datetime` datatype, `WorkYears` is `int`. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server if it matters.

Any tips?

Comment: use: `INSERT INTO SELECT`

Comment: It is not clear from your description what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not inserting new records into `Employees`, you are updating a column in each existing row:

```
UPDATE Employees
SET WorkYears = CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) - YEAR(HireDate) AS INT)
```

**Note 1:** Generally, it is not a good idea to store a derived value along with the value from which it is derived, because `WorkYears` is dependent on today's date. You should drop `WorkYears` column, and compute it in each `SELECT`. You could also create a database view on top of `Employees` to add a calculated column for `WorkYears`.

**Note 2:** Most databases have a facility to compute date difference in the units of your choice. Here is an example for MS Sql Server ([DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, getdate(), HireDate) AS WorkYears 
FROM Employees
```

Comment: Works, great thanks to you, i'm ashamed that i couldn't come to his.
Of course your notices are correct, just was curious if it was possible to do such a computing

Comment: @leronx That's OK - when you start learning SQL, making sense of inserts, updates, and deletes is tricky. An observation about your data model (Note 1) is more fundamental, though.